# place 3 or more components on top of each other and make them fit their parent

Tags: java, swing, awt

What I want to achieve is the following:

- place 3 or more components on top of each other. They are all the same size and are in the topleft position.
- Resize all components to match the size of the parent.

The problem is that I haven't found anything included in swing or awt nor could I think of a way to achieve this goal.

Among what I tried is:

- Use an OverlayLayout, which does not meet the second point
- Create my own Layout by extending OverlayLayout. However, I did not manage to get the desired functionality. This could be due to ignorance. I couldn't find a reference in the javadocs about the method used to set the bounds of each component.
- Create a BorderLayout inside the first component as indicated in other question (lost link). But I would have to make a hierarchy like comp1 -> comp2 -> comp3, one being a relative of the other, and I was not tempted by the idea.

Next, I leave a sample code using OverlayLayout so you can test it:

```
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.OverlayLayout;
import java.awt.Color;

public class Banner extends JPanel {
    public Banner(int color){
        setLayout(new OverlayLayout(this));

        JLabel label = new JLabel("hola mundo");
        label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red));
        add(label);

        label = new JLabel("hele mende");
        label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red));
        add(label);

        setBackground(Color.green);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isOptimizedDrawingEnabled() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

So my question is, is there a way to achieve this using a custom or predefined Layout?

Comment: Use [CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) to do this sort of thing.

Comment: @DevilsHnd tried your proposal, and as I suspected when looking at that tutorial before your comment, CardLayout only allows displaying one element at a time. Whereas I need it to be drawn one on top of the other. But thanks anyway!

Comment: Add each component to its parent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## You could...

Make use of a `GridBagLayout`, it will give you control over the positioning of the components...

[image]

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.LayoutManager;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setBorder(new EmptyBorder(32, 32, 32, 32));
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            BannerPane banner = new BannerPane();
            banner.add(new JLabel("I was added first"));
            banner.add(new JLabel("I was added second"));
            banner.add(new JLabel("I was added third"));

            add(banner);
        }
    }

    public class BannerPane extends JPanel {
        private GridBagConstraints defaultConstraints;

        public BannerPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            defaultConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
            defaultConstraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
            defaultConstraints.gridx = 0;
            defaultConstraints.gridy = 0;
            defaultConstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        }

        @Override
        public Component add(Component comp) {
            super.add(comp, defaultConstraints);
            return comp;
        }

        @Override
        public void add(Component comp, Object constraints) {
            super.add(comp, defaultConstraints);
        }

        @Override
        public Component add(Component comp, int index) {
            super.add(comp, defaultConstraints, index);
            return comp;
        }

        @Override
        public Component add(String name, Component comp) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported");
        }

        @Override
        public void add(Component comp, Object constraints, int index) {
            super.add(comp, defaultConstraints, index);
        }
    }
}
```

## You could...

Fix your `BannerLayout` to correctly calculate the `preferred` and `minimum` sizes correctlt

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.LayoutManager;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setBorder(new EmptyBorder(32, 32, 32, 32));
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            JPanel banner = new JPanel(new BannerLayout());
            banner.add(new JLabel("I was added first"));
            banner.add(new JLabel("I was added second"));
            banner.add(new JLabel("I was added third"));

            add(banner);
        }
    }

    public class BannerLayout implements LayoutManager {
        // add the component, in my case nothing needs to be done
        @Override
        public void addLayoutComponent(String name, Component comp) {
        }

        // Remove the component. Normally, a cleaning would be done,
        // but I did not see it as necessary
        @Override
        public void removeLayoutComponent(Component comp) {

        }

        // I get the preferred size. Since I want the size to be
        // the same as the parent, so I return that same.
        @Override
        public Dimension preferredLayoutSize(Container parent) {
            int width = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
            int height = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
            for (Component child : parent.getComponents()) {
                width = Integer.max(width, child.getPreferredSize().width);
                height = Integer.max(height, child.getPreferredSize().height);
            }
            Insets insets = parent.getInsets();
            return new Dimension(width + insets.left + insets.right, height + insets.top + insets.top);
        }

        // The minimum size is the same as the preferred one
        @Override
        public Dimension minimumLayoutSize(Container parent) {
            int width = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
            int height = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
            for (Component child : parent.getComponents()) {
                width = Integer.max(width, child.getMinimumSize().width);
                height = Integer.max(height, child.getMinimumSize().height);
            }
            Insets insets = parent.getInsets();
            return new Dimension(width + insets.left + insets.right, height + insets.top + insets.top);
        }

        // I give the same size and position to all the components.
        @Override
        public void layoutContainer(Container parent) {
            for (Component comp : parent.getComponents()) {
                comp.setBounds(0, 0, parent.getWidth(), parent.getHeight());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## Which is better?

That, I think, would be a matter of opinion.  I tend to prefer the layout manager approach, as that's its domain of responsibility, however, with the custom component you could always ensure new components are set to the `0` position and change the rendering order (so that new components always appear on top)

Comment: Thanks for the help and advice! Although I wanted to clarify that the miscalculation of the preferred and the minimum size are due to the fact that all the components measure the same (which makes the for loop unnecessary) and there are no insets. Also, I don't want the parent to adapt to the layout, I want the layout to adapt to the parent. I didn't know about the GridBagLayout, thanks!

Comment: In any case, I have been considering that since it deals with images, it is not convenient for me to use components for each one, but to write my own algorithm to draw them optimally. I don't need those images to process events or have bounds. When I have something set up, I'll post the answer for the specific case, but I'll accept yours as it's more general and focused on the problem.

Comment: @DanteS. Yes, as a general recommendation, I would follow a custom painting route in those cases. When asking questions, it's helpful if you provide those details, as it would help us to better provide you with possibly better solutions you may not have thought about

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind next time! I hope your answer will help someone in the future who is not working with images.

Answer (score 0):

Note: This answer is only for those looking to have many images on top of each other and control the order in which they are displayed dynamically.

---

One approach that can be taken to the scenario mentioned in the note is to use a JLabel with an icon. This icon is reused every time the jlabel needs to be redrawed. Every time we make a change to the internal list of images, we redraw the icon. We can make it automatic and have it run when there is a change and once the events have been processed.

The following code applies that approach. Pressing "+" adds an image of random size and color, and pressing "-" removes a random image.

**Banner.java**

```
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Banner extends JLabel{
    private List<Image> images;

    // this field indicates if a redraw request has already been sent
    private boolean redraw_sent;

    public Banner(){
        this.images = new ArrayList<Image>();
    }

    // this function redraws the icon of the jlabel
    private void redrawIcon(){
        this.redraw_sent = false;

        int w = 0;
        int h = 0;

        for(Image image:this.images){
            w = Math.max(w, image.getWidth(null));
            h = Math.max(h, image.getHeight(null));
        }

        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();

        // we draw the pictures
        for(Image subimg:this.images){
            g2d.drawImage(subimg, 0, 0, null);
        }

        ImageIcon icon = (ImageIcon) getIcon();

        if(icon == null){
            icon = new ImageIcon();
            setIcon(icon);
        }

        icon.setImage(image);
        repaint();
    }

    // We make the redraw happen after all events are processed, it has no effect if redraw_sent is true
    public void redraw(){
        if(!this.redraw_sent){
            EventQueue.invokeLater(this::redrawIcon);
            this.redraw_sent = true;
        }
    }

    public void addImage(Image img){
        this.images.add(img);
        redraw();
    }

    public void removeImage(int index){
        this.images.remove(index);
        redraw();
    }

    public int imageCount(){
        return this.images.size();
    }
}
```

**Application.java**

```
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

public class Application extends JFrame {
    private Banner banner;

    public Application(){
        setSize(800, 600);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        this.banner = new Banner();
        this.banner.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        this.banner.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.green));
        add(this.banner);

        bind(KeyEvent.VK_PLUS, e -> {
            Random random = new Random();

            int w = random.nextInt(100);
            int h = random.nextInt(100);
            int r = random.nextInt(256);
            int g = random.nextInt(256);
            int b = random.nextInt(256);

            BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();
            g2d.setColor(new Color(r, g, b));
            g2d.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
            g2d.dispose();

            this.banner.addImage(image);
        });

        bind(KeyEvent.VK_MINUS, e ->{
            Random random = new Random();

            this.banner.removeImage(random.nextInt(this.banner.imageCount()));
        });
    }

    public void bind(int keycode, int modifiers, Consumer<ActionEvent> consumer){
        getRootPane().getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(keycode, modifiers), keycode);
        getRootPane().getActionMap().put(keycode, new ConsumerAction(consumer));
    }

    public void bind(int keystroke, Consumer<ActionEvent> action){
        bind(keystroke, 0, action);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application app = new Application();
        app.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

**ConsumerAction.java**

```
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

public class ConsumerAction extends AbstractAction {
    private Consumer<ActionEvent> consumer;

    public ConsumerAction(Consumer<ActionEvent> consumer){
        this.consumer = consumer;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        this.consumer.accept(e);
    }
}
```